# Finding sum of coefficients from known constant term

Tags: functions, polynomials

I am having some trouble in math. It is basic stuff but I cannot seem to find anything to clear it up for me. Thanks in advance to any who answers.

The Constant Term of $P(x+2)$ is $5.$ Find sum of the coefficients of $P(3x-1).$

Answer (score 1):

To find the sum of coefficients in a polynomial $f(x)$, find $f(1)$. The constant term of a polynomial $g(x)$ is the value $g(0)$.

Applying this to your question:

- The constant term of $P(x+2)$ is $5$ means that $P(2) = 5$.
- The sum of coefficients of $P(3x-1)$ is $P(3\cdot 1 - 1) = P(2) = 5$.

Comment: Thank you so much... I see now that what I did wrong was that I simply placed 0 in stead of x+2. *sigh* I am not brilliant in mathematics. Thank you George.